# Generate Ethereum account in a JSON/UTC v3

Tags: accounts, account-generation

What are some trustful ways to generate an Ethereum account in a JSON/UTC v3 format? I know some web wallets, but I would prefer a very used/well-known desktop or plugin wallet.
Metamask does not allow me to generate this format. It only allows me to export the private key in plain text.

Comment: MyCrypto has a desktop app that can create JSON files

Answer (score 1):

you can try Vanity ETH, it can even create a custom prefix for your address
https://github.com/MyEtherWallet/VanityEth

Answer (score 0):

I developed a small script for that.

```
const ethers  = require('ethers');
require("dotenv").config();
const fs = require('fs');

let wallet = ethers.Wallet.createRandom();
const password = process.env.PASSWORD_WALLET;
const promisseJSON = wallet.encrypt( password);
promisseJSON.then((jsonWallet) => {
    fs.writeFileSync("teste.json", jsonWallet);
});
```